# avahi-daemon fails to start with "Failed to chroot(): Permission denied". But only without stderr-IO-redirection

Tags: io-redirection, chroot, stderr, avahi

After a recent upgrade, avahi-daemon is not starting up anymore. Furthermore, the behaviour differs whether if I redirect stderr to a file or not.

If I run avahi with the debugging option (`avahi-daemon --debug`), I get the following output:

```
Found user 'avahi' (UID 84) and group 'avahi' (GID 84).
Successfully dropped root privileges.
avahi-daemon 0.6.32 starting up.
Failed to chroot(): Permission denied
chroot.c: chroot() helper started
chroot.c: chroot() helper got command 0d
avahi-daemon 0.6.32 exiting.
chroot.c: chroot() helper got command 0c
chroot.c: chroot() helper exiting with return value 0
```

If I add stderr IO-redirection (`avahi-daemon --debug 2>avahi.stderr`), I get different behaviour:

On the terminal (`stdout`), I get

```
File size limit exceeded
```

and `avahi.stderr` now contains

```
Found user 'avahi' (UID 84) and group 'avahi' (GID 84).
Successfully dropped root privileges.
```

But, no avahi-process is running.

When I just redirect `2>/dev/stdin`, I get the same behaviour as without redirection.

Corresponding strace-outputs:

`strace avahi-daemon --debug`:

Due to size limitation in stackexchange, this one is in a pastebin:
http://paste.pound-python.org/show/J1sYeeXcKYKlHxN6QAX0/

`strace avahi-daemon --debug 2>strace.out` (with `File size limit exceeded` on stdout):

Due to size limitation in stackexchange, that one is in a pastebin:
http://paste.pound-python.org/show/VpFokjSr6kmNAA98s4Y6/

And my environment (output of `env`, my non-root-username has been censored) is this:

Due to size limitation of stackexchange, this one is in a pastebin:
http://paste.pound-python.org/show/3s9Qo1WVMB6mLtf15pXp/

Version of avahi:
`avahi-daemon -V` prints `avahi-daemon 0.6.32`.

About the configuration:

```
% ls -la /etc | grep avahi
drwx------   3 root     root       4096 Mar  9 13:29 avahi

% ls -la /etc/avahi
drwx------   3 root root  4096 Mar  9 13:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 242 root root 20480 Mar  9 13:29 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2509 Feb 19 13:52 avahi-autoipd.action
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1747 Feb 19 13:52 avahi-daemon.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1747 Dec 25 18:22 avahi-daemon.conf.pacnew
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    38 Mar  9 13:25 avahi-daemon.conf.pacsave -> /usr/local/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2743 Feb 19 13:52 avahi-dnsconfd.action
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1121 Feb 19 13:52 hosts
drwx------   2 root root  4096 Mar  9 13:29 services
```

Well, `/usr/local/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` is the configuration I usually use, it has been replaced during update. If I use that configuration, I get the same behaviour, and it doesn't matter if `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` is a regular file in-place or a symlink.

Here, I post the content of `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` as it has been for creating this question:

```
# This file is part of avahi.
#
# avahi is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
# published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the
# License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# avahi is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
# ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY
# or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public
# License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
# License along with avahi; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307
# USA.

# See avahi-daemon.conf(5) for more information on this configuration
# file!

[server]
#host-name=foo
#domain-name=local
#browse-domains=0pointer.de, zeroconf.org
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
#allow-interfaces=eth0
#deny-interfaces=eth1
#check-response-ttl=no
#use-iff-running=no
#enable-dbus=yes
#disallow-other-stacks=no
#allow-point-to-point=no
#cache-entries-max=4096
#clients-max=4096
#objects-per-client-max=1024
#entries-per-entry-group-max=32
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

[wide-area]
enable-wide-area=yes

[publish]
#disable-publishing=no
#disable-user-service-publishing=no
#add-service-cookie=no
#publish-addresses=yes
publish-hinfo=no
publish-workstation=no
#publish-domain=yes
#publish-dns-servers=192.168.50.1, 192.168.50.2
#publish-resolv-conf-dns-servers=yes
#publish-aaaa-on-ipv4=yes
#publish-a-on-ipv6=no

[reflector]
#enable-reflector=no
#reflect-ipv=no

[rlimits]
#rlimit-as=
rlimit-core=0
rlimit-data=4194304
rlimit-fsize=0
rlimit-nofile=768
rlimit-stack=4194304
rlimit-nproc=3
```

I use Arch Linux, with OpenRC (i.e. no systemd), and the behaviour is the same whether I use the package `avahi` or `avahi-nosystemd`. I had some problems with avahi before, such that it first did run and then crashed.

What might be going on here?

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro: Done.

Comment: Seeing that /etc/avahi/ was only accessible by root, canging the permissions to be accessible for everyone solved that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

`/etc/avahi/` needs to be accessible by `avahi-daemon` after it dropped root priviledges.

So, `/etc/avahi/` and all subdirectories should have mode `755`, and all files mode `644`, while they stay owned by user `root` and group `root`.

Comment: Thanks, Rui F Ribeiro, after thinking about your comment I see (the comprimised process can change the configuration files, for example, such that at the next start it can be started with a modified configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Related to another mentioned issue, you get a "File size limit exceeded" error from avahi-daemon because it sets its file size rlimit to 0 in its configuration, and your redirection to a file creates a file with a size larger than zero.

To disable this, comment out the rlimit-fsize=0 in avahi configuration, i.e.

```
[rlimits]
#rlimit-as=
rlimit-core=0
rlimit-data=4194304
#rlimit-fsize=0
```

Comment: Don't know why avahi-daemon is flaky in my centos6.9 container but yeah starting with "avahi-daemon --debug --no-rlimits" works around the problem. In my case "failed to start chroot() helper daemon." was a red herring, it reports that even when it successfully starts.